# How to get Grunt CLI to return only the exit code?

Tags: bash, shell, npm, gruntjs

I'm working within a shell script whereby I am calling the grunt command and attempting to capture the result to perform other conditional operations afterward depending on the success or failure of the grunt command.

Is there a way to write something like... *(please excuse the '...' of course)*

```
GRUNT_EXIT_CODE=$(grunt ...);
if [[ $GRUNT_EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]];then echo "Success";else echo "Failure";fi
```

... so that grunt outputs only the exit code?

Comment: The `grunt` command exits with one of [these exit codes](https://gruntjs.com/api/exit-codes)   Consider assigning the `$?` [special parameter](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) to your `GRUNT_EXIT_CODE` variable. For instance change your first line of code to the following instead:  `grunt ...; GRUNT_EXIT_CODE=$?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@RobC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611459/robc) answered this question in his comment on the original post:

> *"Consider assigning the `$?` [special parameter](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) to your `GRUNT_EXIT_CODE` variable. For instance change your first line of code to the following instead:"*
>
> ```
> grunt ...;
> GRUNT_EXIT_CODE=$?
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If `grunt` sets a proper exit code, then you can simply check that:

```
if grunt ...; then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure"
fi
```

If you are not interested in the output from the command, then you can redirect stdout and possibly stderr to /dev/null:

```
grunt ... >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I'm not asking about shell scripting, I'm asking about how to get grunt to return the exit code only. The conditional statement in my question was provided for context only.

Comment: I think I showed you how to discard output from a command?